# How can I add a new language in Liferay 7?

Tags: liferay, liferay-theme, liferay-7, liferay-hook

My problem is how to add new language like thailand language in `liferay 7`. 
When I inspect the existing flag I see that the image is not png but it is svg, but I can't add new language with icon.
In this `page.jsp` I see that the constructor of image is automatically generated.

This code describes the generation of svg image

```
<svg class="lexicon-icon lexicon-icon-<%= image %>" role="img" title="<%= HtmlUtil.escapeAttribute(LanguageUtil.get(resourceBundle, label)) %>" <%= InlineUtil.buildDynamicAttributes(dynamicAttributes) %>>
    <use xlink:href="<%= Validator.isNotNull(src) ? src : themeDisplay.getPathThemeImages() + "/lexicon/icons.svg" %>#<%= image %>" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have followed all the steps in this [Liferay blog](https://web.liferay.com/web/salman.khan/blog/-/blogs/add-a-new-language-to-liferay-detailed-step-by-step-), adding the flag in Liferay 7 requires:

1. Create a new theme, or modify existing theme to :

   - add your flag file in SVG format as `images\lexicon\flags-xx-YY.svg` (where xx-YY is your locale, case-sensitive)
   - open the file `icons.svg` in the same folder and add your flag SVG elements as a `symbol` among the other symbol elements:

     `</symbol><symbol id="xx-yy" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
     <rect y="64" fill="#B0BEC9" width="512" height="384"/>
     <rect x="16" y="80" width="480" height="352" fill="#fff"/>
     <rect ..... />
     <circle .... />
     </symbol><symbol id="zh-cn" viewBox="0 0 512 512">`

     2. Deploy, or re-deploy, the theme and choose it as the active theme for the pages you want.
     3. Clear the browser cache if needed.