# How to add flag icons in admin-theme in Liferay DXP

Tags: liferay, liferay-theme, liferay-7

I am working with Liferay DXP. I would like to add some flag icons to some languages.

In Liferay 6.2 I can do it with a hook which adds the flags icons in the control-panel (now for Liferay DXP is admin-theme) theme and/or classic-theme. For instance, I would like using the flag icon in web content localization.

Someone know how to do it in Liferay DXP?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/is-cross-posting-wrong-to-an-external-site

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 2):

Flag icons are now in SVG and have to be deployed through a theme. See the answer to this question:  [how can i add a new language in liferay 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394800/how-can-i-add-a-new-language-in-liferay-7)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can add svg icon & language icon in liferay admin theme as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46337507/how-to-add-language-icons-in-liferay-dxp). This works for me, you can try this solution.