# How to add language icons in liferay DXP

Tags: liferay-7

How to add the Language icon image in liferay 7(liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga4).

I have followed the steps mentioned in following article,

https://web.liferay.com/web/salman.khan/blog/-/blogs/add-a-new-language-to-liferay-detailed-step-by-step-
After the language configuration I can be able to see the languages but not the flags on web content forms.

So I created the custom theme to add the language file and added **th_TH.png** file in theme\src\images\language\th_TH.png. But din't work.

Then I tried the implementing the lexicon-icon approach mention in,
[how can i add a new language in liferay 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394800/how-can-i-add-a-new-language-in-liferay-7)

Still I am not able to see the language images.

Please refer the screenshot for details,
[Theme-layout and file location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pOuS.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a custom icon that is not supported yet you need to add 2 artefacts into the theme. Liferay using 2 things for displaying icons. Somewhere it uses png flag and somewhere svg you need to adjust both.

Have a look at this sample project. https://github.com/mir333/custom-flag-admin-theme

It takes the admin theme of Liferay (it is a copy so it needs to be kept in sync with updates) and adds a new flag to the admin theme. The magic is in adding the flag into the lexicon. Under the hood, it takes the added flag svg files and recompiles the icons.svg files to include it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried to build the custom-flag-admin-theme but can 't generate the War file. Can you please let me know from where I can get the default admin-theme source code,so that I can check out and build?

Comment: I added a README file to the repo. Check it out.

Comment: Hello Miroslav, I am  getting heap size error while deploying admin-theme
09:28:34,917 INFO  [fileinstall-D:/LifeRay/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga4/osgi/war][PluginPackageUtil:1007] Reading plugin package for admin-theme
09:28:42,250 WARN  [fileinstall-D:/LifeRay/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga4/osgi/war][com_liferay_portal_osgi_web_wab_extender:103] [admin-theme_1.0.0 [535]] Error while creating extension 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I tried increasing the heap memory as well but still no luck.
Any suggesssions?

Comment: What is your mem setting? This is highly irregular behaviour. Can you upload the full stack trace somewhere?

Comment: I am running liferay with default memory settings. Just downloaded  Liferay CE GA4 edition and tried to deploy admin-theme war. Also my computer has 8 GB ram. I am getting out of memory error while Reading the plugin packages for admin-theme.war

Comment: I have create the video for the same hope this will help [link] https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/liferay-error/20171017_135131.mp4

Comment: Please download the video

Comment: Hi @chandrakantlotke I'm unable to download the file.

Comment: Hi Miroslav, Please try this new link [link] https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/liferay-error/20171017_135131.zip

Comment: The sample is from an old project so it works fine on ga1 but has problems with the newer releases. Probably the deps are outdated. I have a look and update the sample.

Comment: Thanks for the solution,now I am able to deploy the my-admin-theme.war. Howvever After selecting the My Admin in Control panel ->Configuration->instance settings-> Miscellaneous-> Default Control Panel Theme
I am not able to see the default icons in many pages. The root cause could be icons.svg is not found. I have attached some screen shots for your reference.
[link]https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/liferay-error/Basic_web_content_add.PNG
[link]https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/liferay-error/Web_Content.PNG
[link]https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/liferay-error/console_logs.PNG

Comment: I fixed a sample. while updating the code I removed some needed changes :) BTW if the answer helps you consider to mark it as answered.

Comment: I am not able to see any changes in code. Kindly push your changes. I guess the removed changes are `.pipe(plugins.rename(config.targetName))` right?

Comment: I did push the changes

Comment: @MiroslavLigas i have similar issue with 7.2, i have created a theme, added svg icons & lexicon icons as described it's still not working, is there any changes i need to follow for 7.2? i will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who still have issue showing the flag, I just want to point out that this helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45907250

As described, open the icons.svg and add your flag's svg code in as a `symbol` with the id "xx-yy" (your language and country code, in lowercase).

The flag does not magically generate just from putting the flags-xx-YY.svg file into lexicon folder, not for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else who is still having issues with this, for some reason adding the png in the 'images/language' folder and adding the svg into the 'images/lexicon' folder did not work for me. I tried threezerothree's suggestion of manually changing the icons.svg file and adding my svg in as a symbol, but this also did not work.

Btw the flag did generate for me in the icons.svg file, but in the build folder not in the src folder. I suspect the same might have been true for threezerothree.

What did end up working for me in the end is manually adding the svg as a symbol in the 'images/clay/icons.svg' file. I'm not sure if this is recommended or is something you're supposed to do, but for whatever reason it is the only thing that ended up working for me.